# Lifespan of a Porlex Mini grinder?

Tags: grinder

I bought a Porlex Mini (the first generation (?) one with the pentagonal connector to the handle) a few years ago and have ground enough coffee for maybe 500, at most 1000 cups. Now the burrs are very worn out and it is impossible to get consistent, fine enough grounds.

Is this the normal lifespan of this grinder resp. its ceramic burrs? What can I do to improve it (now that I bought a replacement set of second generation burrs)? I read about "hacks" where you put tape around the outside burr to keep it from moving around inside the grinder.